# Schema.org Offer priceCurrency doesn't display for Turkish Lira

Tags: currency, schema.org

`<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />` works

`<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="TRY" />`
  doesn't work

TRY is ISO 4217 format Turkish Lira's

Comment: When you say "works" or "doesn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: i can't see product price on my website's google indexed pages. if i use USD it's working. but if i use TRY it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The [`priceCurrency` property](http://schema.org/priceCurrency) expects the currency "in 3-letter ISO 4217 format". Turkish lira has the [ISO 4217 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes) `TRY`.

So your use of Schema.org is appropriate.

If a consumer (like Google Search) can handle "USD" but not "TRY", it’s likely that they don’t support this currency for their feature/product.